# word substitution in bash script

Tags: unix, sed

i have a sed command that looks for a particular word in a text file for pattern matching and then appends a date at the end of the line containing that particular word.
this is the code block

```
some_function() {
        while IFS=: read -r jname state; do
                echo "the job is $name"
                if [[ -n ${name} ]]
                then
                //code to get creation date which works fine
                creation_date="00-00-00_00-00-00"
                sed -i '/^'$job_name':/s/$/':$creation_date'/' $logs_folder/job_state.$today
                fi
        done <"$logs_folder/job_state.$today"
}
```

everything works fine untill the sed command. This command does not work for certain names such as `ARCHIVE-REQUEST - New, ARCHIVE-REQUEST - rss_master`
The sed command throws error

```
sed -i '/^ARCHIVE-REQUEST' - 'rss_master:/s/$/:00-00-00_00-00-00/' file.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated address regex
```

and also escaping these names is not an option because the file from where these names are  taken has other delimiter as well that works with the sed command and since this file is generated dynamically there is no way to hard code delimiters in the sed command

here is my sample file

```
aggressive_cleanup_wrapper_M3
aggressive_cleanup_wrapper_M5
aggressive_cleanup_wrapper_others
aggressive_cleanup_wrapper_R720
ARCHIVE-REQUEST - Approval Pending
ARCHIVE-REQUEST - Archive
ARCHIVE-REQUEST - Lock Period
ARCHIVE-REQUEST - New
ARCHIVE-REQUEST - rss_master
```

How can i modify my sed command to work with the rest of my code?
Can someone please suggest?

Comment: Get rid of it? See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output  if you'd like help (idk if `my sample file` is input or output but it actually appears to be neither since it doesn't contain any `:`s like your script expects in its input, nor does it contain any dates like your script seems to be trying to add). See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You do not understand how escaping works. You need to do this:

```
sed -i '/^'"$job_name"':/s/$/':"$creation_date"'/' ...
```